# Expect command asks for password again in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I am new to Linux Shell Scripting.I need to execute a shell script that gets username, password, host-name, command-to-be-executed as 1,2,3,4 parameters respectively. I used expect command but it prompts for password again.The main theme of this script is to execute a command from a remote server. Password security issues is not a problem. The main issue is that I must not be prompted for password input. I have to run this for about 80 servers, so I cant provide password for each and every time. Please help me solving this.

My script:

```
echo username = $1
echo Password = $2
echo Host-Name = $3
echo Command to Be executed = $4
expect -c "spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no $1@$3 $4; expect \"*assword:*\"; send "$2"; interact
#expect eof
"
```

My Output:

```
username = root
Password = root@123
Host-Name = host-name
Command to Be executed = ls
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no root@host-name ls
root@host-name's password:
~
```

Answer (score 0):

first your index will start at 0 not 1 so username = $0

also you need to set your variables like so: (this is the expect script i use on sever hundred nodes)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set ip [lindex $argv 2]
set command [lindex $argv 3]
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$user\@$ip"
expect "assword:"
send "$password\r";
expect "$ "
send "$command\r"
expect "$ "  
send "exit\r"
```

Comment: connect3.sh: line 6: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "assword:": no such file or directory
connect3.sh: line 8: send: command not found
couldn't read file "$ ": no such file or directory
connect3.sh: line 10: send: command not found
couldn't read file "$ ": no such file or directory
connect3.sh: line 12: send: command not found
These are the errors I got

Comment: can you post the screen output of a normal ssh connection so i can customize the script for your servers?